# GoogleContacts PHP API - parse error

Tags: php, xml, google-contacts-api

I'm getting a 400 (parse error) from the google contacts api and I'm struggling to figure out why. I'm making a call to batch process a set of contacts, stored in "$batch_xml":

```
 // Adding retrieving/refreshing access token
 $access_token = <retrieve access token from DB>
 $refresh_token = <retrieve refresh token from DB>
 if ( access token expired )
 {
     $my_scopes = array(
                        Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN,
                        Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_ME,
                        Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,
                       );
    $this->client = new Google_Client();

    $this->client->setApplicationName( $my_client_application );
    $this->client->setClientId( $my_client_id );
    $this->client->setClientSecret( $my_client_secret );
    $this->client->setScopes($my_scopes);
    $this->client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    if (!$access_token = json_decode($this->client->getAccessToken()))
    {
        LogError("Google login failed: could not fetch auth token.");
        return false;
    }
 }


$UrlToUse = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $UrlToUse );

$curlHeaders = array( "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token,
                      "Depth: 1",
                      "GData-Version: 3.0");

$curlHeaders[] = "Content-Type: application/atom+xml";

// the batch XML goes into the post, length into the header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $batch_xml);
$curlHeaders[]  = "Content-Length: " . strlen($batch_xml);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I've validated the XML, which looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
           xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'
           xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
          xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
    <entry>
       <batch:id>create</batch:id>
       <batch:operation type='insert'/>
       <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact'/>
       <gContact:externalId label="enduser_acnt"  value="7478528" />
       <gd:name>
           <gd:givenName>TestFname</gd:givenName>
           <gd:familyName>TestLname</gd:familyName>
       </gd:name>
       <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="testemail@gmail.com" primary="true" />
       <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true" >5555555555</gd:phoneNumber>
    </entry>

    . . .

</feed>
```

I have tried not setting the Content-Length header, no change. Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: I cannot see the lines where you got the `$access_token`. Can you add them?

Comment: I store the access token in the local database, and retrieve it in the setup to this - including doing a refresh if it's expired. I'll try to extract that from my code, but the core library is used for many other actions, including retrieving and updating groups, all of which works... but I'll work that out.